# Backup software replacement for Acronis

Tags: windows, backup

I have used Acronis for more than a decade. However in the last years their approach to marketing makes it a very unattractive option.

I would be interested in a replacement software with one-off license fee. I use it two-ways:

- C: disk backup, so I can restore system if the disk fails
- regular directories/files backup